# How do I fix enourmous CPU usage & temperature on MacBook Air when trying to install Wine?

Tags: macbook-pro, macports, temperature, cpu, wine

I have a 2012 MacBook Air Intel Core i5 8 GB memory (Mountain Lion).  I am trying to install Wine through MacPorts, but after about a minute of building Wine, CPU usage rapidly rises into the 90s, and the temperature goes from 60 degrees Celcius to 90-95 very quickly.  Both the CPU usage and the temperature continue rising until I shut down my MacBook. The fan becomes very loud and occasionally makes screeching sounds.  I have tried several times and reinstalled MacPorts but to no avail.  What can I do to fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Compiling is CPU intensive.so CPU use goes up to 100% and increases the temp and so fans come on. This is all as designed - What are you trying to change?

Answer (score 3):

The current lineup runs CPU up to 100 C. Is is normal, so you might be able to get something ike SMC fan control to ramp up the fans earlier, but since the CPU clock rate can over heat the blowers, you might not be able to do anything short of externally cooling the case significantly.

Both the clock rate and fans work in conjunction, so upping the fans in turn lowers the clock rate restriction - canceling your efforts to alter the designed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have had increasing problems with CPU and temps, to the point where my mid 2012 macbook air would take 10 minutes to come back from sleep.  I finally opened up the computer, and replaced the thermal paste on the cpu.  I found that about 30% of the cpu surface was lacking paste at all, and the rest was dried and caked.  After cleaning and replacing with Arctic Silver 5, my temps run in the 60's for the most part, and under high load, go into the 90's, but not the 100's like before.  In addition, my system comes back from sleep very quickly - though the cpu goes to 100% and the temps rise rapidly to the high 90's before settling down again.  I would recommend this fix for anyone with temperature problems.